# Interaction between QLineEdit editingFinished signal and button press

Tags: python, pyqt5, qdialog, qmessagebox

I have a `QLineEdit` in a `QDialog` with a `QButtonBox` in the dialog.  The `QLineEdit`'s `editingFinished` signal is connected to a function. The function is called if the QLineEdit loses focus, as expected. When the focus is lost to pressing the Ok button is where I get confused. My signal handler is called, as expected, but the Ok button `accepted()` signal is not emitted. Why is this signal lost? In particular, if the dialog is `exec()`'ed, hitting the OK button when focus is on my `QLineEdit` does not end the dialog, it just invokes the `editingFinished` handler. My handler calls a `QMessageBox`, and this is what appears to be breaking the  `accepted` signal. If I comment it out, then I get the expected behavior.

Is the  `accepted()` signal from the `QMessageBox` interfering with the signal from the `QButtonBox`? If so, what's the right way to handle this?

edit -
Run the code below. Click in the QLineEdit box, then click Ok. You will see a msg box. Click OK on the msg box and you're back in the dialog, with the Ok button having focus and indicating the "down" state. Checking the button with `isDown()` returns false, so it apparently doesn't transition to the down state until myHandler returns. Now comment out the msg_box.exec() line and repeat the steps above. Clicking the Ok button exits the dialog.

The behavior I'm seeking is for the Ok button action (`accepted`) to execute after the return from myHandler(). I know I can `emit` the `accepted` or `rejected` signal from myHandler, but that requires testing which button was pressed. I think I can tell that by checking focus, but I'm hoping there's a cleaner approach. And more generally, I'm curious what's happening to the signals a the pressed button is emitting but seem to be getting lost or gobbled up.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(640, 480)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 440, 621, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 180, 251, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))

class MyDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
  def __init__(self, parent= None):
    QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.myHandler)

  def myHandler(self):
    print ("My handler called")
    msg_box = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
    msg_box.setText("Your Message here")
    msg_box.exec()



if (__name__ == '__main__'):
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  myapp = MyDialog()
  myapp.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your situation. Can you please provide a [mre] to better demonstrate the issue, with a detailed description of the steps to follow?

Comment: A click consists of *a mouse-press and a mouse-release on the same widget*. The focus will switch immediately after the mouse-press, so opening a message-box will stop the button receiving the subsequent mouse-release; thus, no click will occur, and the clicked signal will not be emitted. Your question doesn't really explain what you're trying to achieve, but it seems like poor gui design to use a message-box in that way. If you're trying to perform some kind of validation, there are much better ways to achieve that (e.g. [QValidator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html)).

Comment: @ekhumoro I am using a validator. The message box is to warn that the input, though valid, is dangerous and asks the user if they want to proceed. I suppose I can move this checked into a handler on the "Ok" button, rather than raising the message box on editingFinished.

Comment: @ekhumoro - this helps explain a lot. I added a slot to catch the `pressed()` signal and can now see that it occurs *after* the message box returns. That explains why I couldn't see the `isDown()` state.

Comment: @ekhumoro - validators are useful, but can be incredibly frustrating to a user trying to enter a value and finding themselves unable to do so with no explanation why it's not working.

Comment: @Llaves The normal way to provide that kind of explanation is via [QToolTip](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html) or [QWhatsThis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwhatsthis.html) (or perhaps a Help button that opens a User Manual). Most users will be very irritated by message-boxes constantly appearing whilst they're still making changes. The confirmation message-box should only appear *after* clicking OK - after all, the user may also want to cancel at any time.

Comment: @ekhumoro - yes, my plan is to move the confirmation to the OK handler. Thanks